# Chain Select Option for simple software download form - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I'm looking to create a chain select form, in order to create a download section to download various software/documentation for the products we sell.

I have created a mockup of the basic thing I am trying to achieve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5irM.png]

Are there similar examples or templates available that I could work from?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you can do it in the following way(browser-side):

1. Use jQuery.
2. Create javascript JSON data containers for each list:

   - for list 1: each item/object should have id and name
   - for lists 2 : each item/object should have id, name and master id (referencing to item selected in the previous list)
   - for list 3: each item/object should have id, name, master id, and text that will be shown below
3. Then you use onselect on list 1 to:

   - read iteratively your data container for list 2
   - and select items with proper master id of the selected element from list 1
   - then you update your DOM element with values and id-s
4. You do the same when item on list 2 is selected for list 3
5. When you select item onlist 3:

   - choose proper item from JSON datastore for list 3 and
     display associated text below.